# Alternating table color

Tags: css

I am having trouble getting my CSS to look right. I want alternating colors in my table, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my CSS:

```
table.className tbody tr:nth-child(even){
background-color: white;
}

table.className tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Which browser(s) are you using? Are you sure it supports nth-child?

Comment: Can you show some of the surrounding css and html code, please?

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html and search for ":nth-child()" to see if your browser supports the property. IE8 doesn't support the selector so I would wait a bit before solving this with pure CSS.

Comment: Try the CSS without the tbody.

Comment: Thanks for that link, that's a very helpful table to have as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good. Could be two things, your version of IE that you are using is to old (IE8 and below I believe doesn't support this), or you have these styles being set elsewhere with a !important attached to them.

Comment: Ah, yeah I am doing this in IE8 so that seems to the problem. Shame IE8 doesn't support this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML, there are a couple of possibilities:

- The class name doesn't match
- The `tbody` tag is missing (either way, `tbody` isn't needed in the CSS selector)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reason as to why this may not be working for you. First the CSS code that you are using is CSS3 and may not be supported in the browser you are using: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-browser-support/

Another reason this may not be working is that you have included the "tbody" tag in the CSS which indicates that your html table is setup as such. This is actually a tag that some developers forego, if you html table does not have a "" tag then you must remove it from the CSS in order for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

Given that its been established that you are using IE8 which doesn't support :nth-child in CSS, you can achieve the same thing using jQuery for better cross-browser support:

```
$(function() {
  $("table.className tr:nth-child(even)").css('background-color','white');
  $("table.className tr:nth-child(odd)").css('background-color','grey');
});
```